# Android Studio: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException class android.text.SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: java, android

Can't figure out where this error is coming from.

logcat:

```
04-01 16:51:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1532): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 16:51:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1532): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid type for value: class android.text.SpannableStringBuilder
04-01 16:51:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at com.parse.ParseObject.put(ParseObject.java:2540)
04-01 16:51:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at com.joshuaphilpott.studybuddy.PostSessionActivity.getSessionInfo(PostSessionActivity.java:53)
04-01 16:51:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at com.joshuaphilpott.studybuddy.PostSessionActivity$1.onClick(PostSessionActivity.java:37)
04-01 16:51:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
04-01 16:51:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
04-01 16:51:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-01 16:51:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-01 16:51:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-01 16:51:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-01 16:51:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 16:51:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-01 16:51:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-01 16:51:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-01 16:51:48.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here's the activity i'm getting the error from:

```
public class PostSessionActivity extends Activity {

    EditText eText;
    ParseObject session = new ParseObject("Sessions");
    String str = "";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_postsession);
        setSpinnerVals();
        Parse.initialize(this, "somestring", "someotherstring");

        final Button postButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_postsession);
        postButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                getSessionInfo();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Session Posted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }


    // Get session information and upload to database
    public void getSessionInfo()
    {

        // Get name of session
        eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        session.put("Name", eText.getText());

        // Get what project working on
        eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        session.put("Project", eText.getText());

        // Get gps location
        /*eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        session.put()*/

        session.put("Class", "Android");

        session.saveInBackground();
    }


    public void setSpinnerVals(){
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("Android");
        list.add("Computer Systems Design");
        list.add("Mobile Control of Robots");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    }
}
```

Comment: (unrelated to the question) I think your `Session posted` toast is too early. You are calling `saveInBackground`, meaning you don't know that it has finished when you call the toast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need use:

```
eText.getText().toString()
```

instead of:

```
eText.getText()
```

do this for all EditText value

getText return `editable` not `value` on EditText you need cast that to String

i think it's very good to change `EditText` object while changing widget, you use `eText` for three `EditText` widget on:

```
 eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 session.put("Name", eText.getText());

 // Get what project working on
 eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
 session.put("Project", eText.getText());

 // Get gps location
 /*eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
 session.put()*/
```

you can use something like:

```
 EditText eText1 , eText2 , eText3;
```

and in code

```
 eText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 session.put("Name", eText.getText());

 // Get what project working on
 eText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
 session.put("Project", eText.getText());

 // Get gps location
 /*eText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
 session.put()*/
```

Comment: regarding your last point, I don't see any good reason for it, since the edittexts are not reused. I would inline them altogether.

Comment: I think it's better for understanding and changing code in future, did not? thanks for your mention @njzk2

Comment: if you are intending to reuse it in another methods, yes, definitely. otherwise I think it only clutters the code. (especially since the variable have a very unspecific name)